Issue in Sticky Header in Angular AG Grid - Header Freeze Not Working
If we're using normal table functionalities we will use the below kind of methods to fix the header sticky which will keep the position sticky on scrolling the table, but when its comes to AGGrid i cannot able to achieve this kind of functionality
//Normal_way_of_making_header_sticky

.table {
  thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
}

I tried to enable to vertical scroll with sticky header
